# Can't get simple ember-data working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Learning Ember.js + Ember-data. I have an API endpoint at `http://locahost:3000`

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    url:"http://localhost:3000"
});
App.Client = DS.Model.extend({
    shortName: DS.attr('string'),
    longName: DS.attr('string')
});
var clients = this.store.find('client');
console.log(clients);
```

Using final Ember.js 1.0 and Ember-data 1.0.0 beta2. Getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

Wondering if there are updated tutorials on ember-data. This tutorial: http://twbrandt.github.io/2013/02/22/Ember-Data-Quick-Start-Guide/ is outdated.

Comment: You should drop `revision` from your store. It's obsolete since Ember Data 1.0.0-beta1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.store` inside of some route. For example:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    url:"http://localhost:3000"
});
App.Client = DS.Model.extend({
    shortName: DS.attr('string'),
    longName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.store.find('client').then(function(clients) {
            console.log(clients);
        });                
    }
});
```